# android Json not able to fetch data from a webservice using volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String url = "http://oilpeople.talenetic.com/api/SearchJob?limit=5&jobkeyword=oil&countrytext=UnitedKingdom&location=London[GreaterLondon]&apikey=1111111111&siteid=1";

        JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // the response is already constructed as a JSONObject!
                        try {
                            JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("joblist");
                            String name = array.getString(1),
                                    network = array.getString(2);
                            String[] myList ={name,network};
                            ListView mlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.jsonlist);

                            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myList);
                            mlist.setAdapter(adapter);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });

        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonRequest);


    }


}
```

I am trying to fetch json data from this link

`http://oilpeople.talenetic.com/api/SearchJob?limit=5&jobkeyword=oil&countrytext=United Kingdom&location=London [Greater London]&apikey=1111111111&siteid=1`

Everything works fine except i am not able to display the fetched data! i want to know if i am fetching it in a correct way. so please go throught the link and check if i am fetching the data correctly. ThankYou.

Comment: joblist has two json object and your parsing string so it wont show anything

Comment: First get json object from response and from this json object then get your json array

Comment: Can you please tell me how i should access the array because I am new to this . ThankYou

Comment: instead of String name = array.getString(1), network = array.getString(2); do JSONObject name = array.getJsonObject(1), network = array.getJsonObject(2);

Answer (score 0):

Use optJSONArray instead of getJSONArray, it will return value if that key have any values else it won't affect any flow.

By using this you can avoid null pointer Exception

```
try {
    if(response !=null) { //check jsonObject is null or not
        JSONArray array = response.optJSONArray("joblist");
        String name = array.optString("jobid"),
                network = array.optString("jobtitle");
        String[] myList = {name, network};
        ListView mlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.jsonlist);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);
        mlist.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Do u got any crashes? if yes means please post all the logs

Answer (score 0):

I think following will be the error.
An extra 'd' object will get in the response.

```
if(response!=null && response.length>0){
JSONObject objmain = new JSONObject(response.getString("d"));
JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("joblist");
//your required code here//
//it will work//
}
```

Comment: In the response You will get an extra 'd' parameter.
So for that you have to first get the Object for 'd' and the Carry your regular code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one Objects then use this

```
for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
JSONObject jresponse = response.getJSONObject(i);
String stringValue= jresponse.getString("string_key);
Log.d("string_key", stringValue);
```

}

and if you have only one object then use below code

```
try {
    JSONObject jresponse = response.getJSONObject(0);
    String stringValue= jresponse.getString("string_key");
    Log.d("string_key",stringValue);
}catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```